# Redirect loop detected Dart

Tags: json, rest, dart

i have the following code in dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() async {
  final url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  final response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

it works correctly, but when I change the query url to
http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbz8vTxNDRy9_Y2NQ13CDA0sTIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wBmoxN_FydLAGAgNTKEK8DkRrACPGwpyQyMMMj0VAcySpRM!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_61L0H0G0J0VSC0AC4GLFAD2003/res/id=buscaResultado/c=cacheLevelPage/=/?timestampAjax=1534624870817&concurso=1703

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() async {
  final url =
      'http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbz8vTxNDRy9_Y2NQ13CDA0sTIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wBmoxN_FydLAGAgNTKEK8DkRrACPGwpyQyMMMj0VAcySpRM!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_61L0H0G0J0VSC0AC4GLFAD2003/res/id=buscaResultado/c=cacheLevelPage/=/?timestampAjax=1534624870817&concurso=1703';
  final response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

the following error occurs:

```
    Unhandled exception:
Redirect loop detected
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:64:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:171:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:34:5)
#3      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:47:34)
#4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:167:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      get (package:http/http.dart:47:3)
```

Why does this occur? when I use the browser it works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first request responds with a cookie and `HttpStatus.movedTemporarily`, a redirect to the same URL.
The browser sends the cookie on its 2nd request when following up the redirect.
This 2nd request completes with `HttpStatus.ok` because it contained the expected cookie.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  var url =
      'http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbz8vTxNDRy9_Y2NQ13CDA0sTIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wBmoxN_FydLAGAgNTKEK8DkRrACPGwpyQyMMMj0VAcySpRM!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_61L0H0G0J0VSC0AC4GLFAD2003/res/id=buscaResultado/c=cacheLevelPage/=/?timestampAjax=1534624870817&concurso=1703';
  var isRedirect = true;

  while (isRedirect) {
    final client = http.Client();
    final request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url))
          ..followRedirects = false
          ..headers['cookie'] = 'security=true';
    print(request.headers);
    final response = await client.send(request);

    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.movedTemporarily) {
      isRedirect = response.isRedirect;
      url = response.headers['location'];
      // final receivedCookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
    } else if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      print(await response.stream.join(''));
    }
  }
}
```

Consider reading the `set-cookie` header from the first response and use the content as cookie for the next request instead of hardcoding it.